# Input 2 tables in R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I want to have a provision to input 2 tables namely train and test for further analysis in R shiny dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.
Assuming your files are in a format that you can read with read.table(), this example will be a working start for you.

You can use `fileInput()` to input files, this can be any format from .csv, .txt or .RData or any other file type you need.

You use `fileInput("Table1",...)` in the UI. And then in the server() function of your app you can access the input files by `input$Table1`. Specifically, the file is uploaded and saved at a temporary location that you can access with `input$Table1$datapath`.

With this file location you should be able to do whatever you want to do with the data that is now uploaded to your shiny App. In the example below I only read the data using `read.table()` and then show the data in two datatables in the UI.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# A minimal dashboard page
#   Sidebar for file inputs
#   Main body to show 2 datatables
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Two tables for further analysis"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    h2("fileInput() to upload files"),
    fileInput("Table1", "Input file for train data"),
    fileInput("Table2", "Input file for test data")
  ),
  # A body for two datatables to show the data input
  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(width=6,
               DT::dataTableOutput("Train")),
        column(width=6,
               DT::dataTableOutput("Test"))
  )
)
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Train <- DT::renderDataTable({
    # NULL if no input given
    if (is.null(input$Table1)) return(NULL)

    # Else... read table (input$Table1 is a list of componenent - the 'datapath' field is the temp file location)
    read.table(input$Table1$datapath) # Assuming you have a file to read with read.table()
  })

  # Using output$Test - we can use datatableOutput("Test") to show the datatable in the UI
  output$Test <- DT::renderDataTable({
    # NULL if no input given
    # 
    if (is.null(input$Table2)) return(NULL)
    # Else... read table (input$Table1 is a list of componenent - the 'datapath' field is the temp file location)
    read.table(input$Table2$datapath) # Assuming you have a file to read with read.table()
  })

  # You can of course read the data for your own purpose
  #   Not for a datatable, but to do follow-up analysis
  #   
  #   Further, you can also upload .RData files for example - or any other file.
}

# Run the shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please be a little more specific next time and give an example of what you have already tried.
I have no clue what type of data format you are trying to work with... Hope this helps!